# Combinatorics: Number of permutations from $1$ to $60$, with cyclic permutation of length $l > 30$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, harmonic-numbers, permutation-cycles

In a game, $60$ kids have the chance to win presents. The organiser gives every kid a number between $1$ and $60$, so that all kids have different numbers. In a room, there is a cupboard with $60$ drawers.

Now the organiser randomly puts the number of exactly $1$ kid into each of the drawers and closes them afterwards.

The kids enter the room sequentially. Every kid is allowed to to open $30$ drawers in a random order and has to close them with its content afterwards.

If all kids find their numbers in their drawers, then every kid gets a present. If not, nobody gets any present.

Before the first kid enters the room, all kids can talk to each other, after that, they are not allowed to do anymore.

**a)** How can one find out the number of permutations from $1$ to $60$, which have a cyclic permutation of length $l > 30$?

**b)** How can one use a) to develop a strategy for the kids, so that all kids get a present with the probability of $1-H_{60}-H_{30}$?

$H_n$ is the n-th harmonic number with $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$

So to structure this a bit:

- $60$ kids
- numbers $1,..,60$
- drawers $1,..,60$
- every kid opens $30$ drawers

I know that the notation for cyclic permutation goes as following:

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and different numbers $i_1,i_2,...,i_k \in [n]$ the cycle $(i_1,i_2,...,i_k)$ denotes the permutation $\pi \in S_n$ with

[image]

I'm pretty new to combinatorics, so I don't know how to find out the number of permutations from $1$ to $60$, which have a cyclic permutation of length $l > 30$...

Comment: There are $30$ kids and $60$ drawers, and he puts the number of exactly one kid in each drawer.  Is each kid's number used twice, then?

Comment: @saulspatz My bad, got lost in all these numbers. Edited.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_prisoners_problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm summarizing the Wikipedia article mentioned in the comments.

### Disjoint Cycle Notation

Any permutation $\pi$ can be decomposed in the composition of *disjoint cycles*, where
$$\pi = (\mathrm{cycle 1})(\mathrm{cycle 2})...$$

For example, the permutation $\pi(1)=3$, $\pi(2)=4$, $\pi(3)=1$,$\pi(4)=2$ can be written as
$$\pi = (1,3)(2,4)$$

Note that $\pi=(3,1)(2,4)=(3,1)(4,2)=(1,3)(4,2)$ are equivalent.

### Counting the permutations

Now we find the number of permutations of $Z_60$ which have a cycle of length greater than 30.

First we note that a permutation can only have one such cycle (since cycles are disjoint). We define $l$ to be the  length of this cycle. Then we note that two such permutations ($l > 30$) *are different* if the lengths of their largest cycle are different. So we can say that the number of permutations with $l>30$ is equal to
$$\sum_{k=31}^{60}{n_k}$$
where $n_k$ is the number of permutations with $l=k$.

Now we just need to calculate $n_l$. We know that there are $60\choose{l}$ possible ways to choose the *values* of the largest cycle, and there are $\frac{l!}{l} = (l-1)!$ ways to *order* the values *in the notation* to produce a different cycle (the position of the first element is a free choice, but after that the representation is determined, so there are $l$ ways to write the same cycle). For the values not in the main cycle, there are $(60-l)!$ different permutations. Therefore,
$$n_l = {60 \choose l} (l-1)! (60-l)! = \frac {60!} l$$

Now we just directly sum the $n_l$ to find the number $n$ of such permutations.

$$n = 60! (\frac 1 {31} + ... \frac 1 {60})$$

### Probability

We know there are $60!$ permutations in total so the probability a randomly selected permutation has a cycle of length greater than 30 is

$$n/60! = (\frac 1 {31} + ... \frac 1 {60}) \approx 0.68488$$

Therefore the probability a permutation has no cycle of length greater than 30 is $$1-0.68488 \approx 0.31512$$